# Are there any ways to update gnome 43 in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, 22.04

Question is as title says. Is it possible in any way? Recommended or not recommended ways? I really like gnome 43.

Answer (score 0):

There is simply no way for someone without thorough technical skills in software compilation.

Gnome 43 is available on Ubuntu 22.10, which is one of the very first distributions shipping the desktop. Upgrading to Ubuntu 22.10 is the only recommended way to obtain Gnome 43 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 is actually EoL, so it's not recommended, and upgrading to this version is not supported.